# Finding elements without a pair in given list #python

Tags: python, list

I'm new into coding and I'm learning by myself at my home. Right now I'm doing some exercises to practise.

I've got something like that:

> Given integer coordinates of three vertices of a rectangle whose sides are parallel to coordinate axes, find the coordinates of the fourth vertex of the rectangle.

I figured out that every single point needs to be repeated two times. So my idea for doing this is to make a list with those 6 elements and find 2 elements which don't have a pair. And here I need your help because I don't know how I can find those 2 elements without a pair. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. Regards.
Daniel
(Sorry for my broken english, I'm not english speaking person)

Comment: Please write code on your own first...there are plenty of other website which can help you with logic building...SO is not for this. Thank you

Comment: Hello there, please take a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and more specifically the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do show what you have tried, then people might be able help you figure out why what you had was wrong, or maybe something you have overseen.

Comment: There are much easier ways of getting the fourth vertex. Test what happens if you add your vectors. Check [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html)